# How to initiate UIAlertController from a delegate method?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

My code is quite basic. I have 2 ViewControllers. On the first viewController named "FirstScreen" there is a button, which via modal segue takes me to the second screen, where there is also a button. The "SecondScreen" has a protocol with 1 method, to which the "FirstScreen" is conforming to. So basically I'm trying to call the `UIAlertController` from that method, while pressing the button of the "SecondScreen". As result I get:

> "Warning: Attempt to present.....on....whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

I know I could have embedded a navigation controller into my storyboard and the alert would work, but that's not the case for me. Also I do wanna call Alert this way because of necessity of knowing `CLAuthorizationStatus`.

> **So maybe is there any way of getting the status directly from the
>   "SecondScreen" ?**

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class FirstScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func firstTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let selectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondScreen
        present(selectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        selectionVC.delegate = self
    }
}

extension FirstScreen: LocationPermissionDelegate {

    func checkLocationStatus() {

        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Just a message", message: "HEYYY!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol LocationPermissionDelegate {
    func checkLocationStatus()
}

class SecondScreen: UIViewController {

    var delegate: LocationPermissionDelegate?

    @IBAction func secondTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        delegate?.checkLocationStatus()  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firstvc is currently presenting

```
present(selectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

so you can't present the alert here

```
present(alert, animated: true)
```

Move this

```
func checkLocationStatus() {

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Just a message", message: "HEYYY!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

to the second vc , and do the presentation there

Comment: I moved func `checkLocationStatus()` as suggested and imported CoreLocation in the SecondScreen. All works now, thanks.

Comment: also no need for the delegate any more